# What is the function of this script added to every website in Devtools / elements: "TestCompleteHiddenNodes"?

Tags: javascript, browser

This script is added at the bottom of everye webpage.
In Devtools / elements at the bottom; last script.
It doesn't show up in incognito window.
What is the function of this script?
I tested it in Chrome (latest version) and Edge.

```
   <!--TestCompleteHiddenNodes-->
    <script istestcompletehiddennode="1">
        var g_TestCompleteChromeBrowserAgentScriptHelper12_0 = {
            "addScriptToAgent": function () { }, "removeScriptFromAgent": function () { }, "addCustomScript": function (text) {
                try {
                    eval(text);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.trace(e);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        window["$iocm12"] = {
            "name": "$iocm12", "persistentIdName": "nptcCrBrowserAgentIdentityValue_ver12_0", "contentAgentName": "g_TestCompleteChromeBrowserAgentScriptHelper12_0", "persistentIdValue": 68029, "context": {}, "OBJECTID_NULL": 0, "OBJECTID_WINDOW": -1, "OBJECTID_CONTEXT": -2, "OBJECTID_AGENT": -3, "OBJECTID_IOCM": -4, "objectCache": [], "objectMonikerCache": [], "freeIndexes": [], "nextCacheId": 1, "nextCacheIdStep": 1, "cachedNamespaces": {}, "isObject": function (obj) {

                return (typeof (obj) == "object") || (obj instanceof Object) ||
                    ((typeof (obj) == "undefined") && (obj !== undefined) && (obj.constructor != null));

            }, "getObjectPersistentId": function (obj) {

                if ((typeof (obj) != "object") || (obj == null))
                    return 0;
                var persistentId = obj[this.persistentIdName];
                if (typeof (persistentId) == "undefined") {
                    persistentId = this.persistentIdValue++;
                    obj[this.persistentIdName] = persistentId;
                }
                return persistentId;
            }, "inSandbox": function () {
                    return typeof (c_9B1D14CA_8ADC_4110_B4FE_C428750E198F) == "undefined";
            }, "isCustomElement": function (el) {
                var classes = ['Element', 'HTMLElement', 'HTMLAnchorElement', 'HTMLAppletElement', 'HTMLAreaElement', 'HTMLAudioElement', 'HTMLBaseElement', 'HTMLBaseFontElement', 'HTMLBlockquoteElement', 'HTMLBodyElement',
                    'HTMLBRElement', 'HTMLButtonElement', 'HTMLCanvasElement', 'HTMLDetailsElement', 'HTMLDirectoryElement', 'HTMLDivElement', 'HTMLDListElement', 'HTMLEmbedElement', 'HTMLFieldSetElement', 'HTMLFontElement',
                    'HTMLFormElement', 'HTMLFrameElement', 'HTMLFrameSetElement', 'HTMLHeadElement', 'HTMLHeadingElement', 'HTMLHRElement', 'HTMLHtmlElement', 'HTMLIFrameElement', 'HTMLImageElement', 'HTMLInputElement',
                    'HTMLKeygenElement', 'HTMLLabelElement', 'HTMLLegendElement', 'HTMLLIElement', 'HTMLLinkElement', 'HTMLMapElement', 'HTMLMarqueeElement', 'HTMLMediaElement', 'HTMLMenuElement', 'HTMLMetaElement',
                    'HTMLMeterElement', 'HTMLModElement', 'HTMLObjectElement', 'HTMLOListElement', 'HTMLOptGroupElement', 'HTMLOptionElement', 'HTMLOutputElement', 'HTMLParagraphElement', 'HTMLParamElement', 'HTMLPictureElement',
                    'HTMLPreElement', 'HTMLProgressElement', 'HTMLQuoteElement', 'HTMLScriptElement', 'HTMLSelectElement', 'HTMLSlotElement', 'HTMLSourceElement', 'HTMLSpanElement', 'HTMLStyleElement', 'HTMLTableCaptionElement',
                    'HTMLTableCellElement', 'HTMLTableColElement', 'HTMLTableElement', 'HTMLTableRowElement', 'HTMLTableSectionElement', 'HTMLTextAreaElement', 'HTMLTitleElement', 'HTMLUListElement', 'HTMLUnknownElement', 'HTMLVideoElement'];
                var isCustom = false;
                if (window.customElements != null)
                    isCustom = window.customElements.get(el.tagName) !== undefined;
                if (!isCustom)
                    isCustom = classes.indexOf(el.constructor.name) < 0;
                return isCustom;
            }, "standardTagNames": ["A", "ABBR", "ADDRESS", "APPLET", "AREA", "ARTICLE", "ASIDE", "AUDIO", "B", "BASE", "BDI", "BDO", "BLOCKQUOTE", "BODY", "BR", "BUTTON", "CANVAS", "CAPTION", "CITE", "CODE", "COL", "COLGROUP", "DATA", "DATALIST", "DD", "DEL", "DETAILS", "DFN", "DIALOG", "DIR", "DIV", "DL", "DT", "EM", "EMBED", "FIELDSET", "FIGCAPTION", "FIGURE", "FONT", "FOOTER", "FORM", "FRAME", "FRAMESET", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "HEAD", "HEADER", "HGROUP", "HR", "HTML", "I", "IFRAME", "IMG", "INPUT", "INS", "KBD", "KEYGEN", "LABEL", "LEGEND", "LI", "LINK", "MAIN", "MAP", "MARK", "META", "METER", "MENU", "MENUITEM", "NAV", "NOSCRIPT", "OBJECT", "OL", "OPTGROUP", "OPTION", "OUTPUT", "P", "PARAM", "PICTURE", "PRE", "PROGRESS", "Q", "RB", "RP", "RT", "RTC", "RUBY", "S", "SAMP", "SCRIPT", "SECTION", "SELECT", "SLOT", "SMALL", "SOURCE", "SPAN", "STRONG", "STYLE", "SUB", "SUMMARY", "SUP", "SVG", "TABLE", "TBODY", "TD", "TEMPLATE", "TEXTAREA", "TFOOT", "TH", "THEAD", "TIME", "TITLE", "TR", "TRACK", "U", "UL", "VAR", "VIDEO", "WBR"], "canBeCustomElement": function (el) {
                if (!el) return false;
                var tagName = el.tagName || '';
                if (tagName.indexOf('-') >= 0)
                    return true;
                if ((this.standardTagNames.indexOf(tagName) >= 0) && el.getAttribute('is'))
                    return true;
                    return false;
            }, "getNodeInfo": function (node) {
                var node_info = {};
                try {
                    var isElement = (node.nodeType == 1);
                    var isInputElement = (isElement && node.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input');
                    if (!isElement || !node.getAttribute('isTestCompleteHiddenNode')) {
                        node_info.nodeType = node.nodeType;
                        node_info.tagName = node.tagName || '';
                        node_info.className = node.className || '';
                        node_info.inputType = isInputElement ? node.type : '';
                        node_info.inputValue = isInputElement ? node.value : '';
                        node_info.id = (isElement && node.getAttribute('id')) || '';
                        node_info.name = (isElement && node.getAttribute('name')) || '';
                        node_info.role = (isElement && node.getAttribute('role')) || '';
                        node_info.hasNonEmptyTextChild = false;
                        node_info.firstChildIsNonEmptyText = false;
                        node_info.isCustom = (isElement && this.canBeCustomElement(node)) ? this.invoke({ 'method': 'isCustomElement', 'objectId': this.OBJECTID_IOCM, 'flags': 2, 'params': [{ 'objectId': this.calcMoniker(node) }] })["retVal"] : false;
                        node_info.hasShadowRoot = node.shadowRoot != null;
                        var child = node.firstChild;
                        var isFirstChild = true;
                        while (child) {
                            if (child.nodeType == 3) {
                                var txt = child.data;
                                if (txt && txt.replace(/^[ \n\r\t]+/, '')) {
                                    node_info.hasNonEmptyTextChild = true;
                                    if (isFirstChild)
                                        node_info.firstChildIsNonEmptyText = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            child = child.nextSibling;
                            isFirstChild = false;
                        }
                        node_info.hasChildren = node_info.hasNonEmptyTextChild || (isElement ? node.childElementCount > 0 : node.hasChildNodes());
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    console.trace(e);
                }
                return JSON.stringify(node_info);
            }, "getObjectMoniker": function (objectId) {

                if (typeof (objectId) == "string")
                    return objectId;

                if (objectId == this.OBJECTID_NULL)
                    return "";

                if (objectId == this.OBJECTID_WINDOW)
                    return "window";

                if (objectId == this.OBJECTID_CONTEXT)
                    return "window[\"" + this.name + "\"].context";

                if (objectId == this.OBJECTID_AGENT)
                    return "window[\"" + this.contentAgentName + "\"]";

                if (objectId == this.OBJECTID_IOCM)
                    return "window[\"" + this.name + "\"]";

                var obj = this.objectCache[objectId];
                if (obj === null)
                    return "";

                var moniker = this.objectMonikerCache[objectId];
                if (typeof (moniker) != "string")
                    moniker = "";

                if ((obj === 0) && (moniker != "")) {
                    try {
                        obj = eval(moniker);
                        if (obj !== undefined)
                            this.objectCache[objectId] = obj;
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                    return moniker;
                }

                try {
                    var newObj = null;
                    if (moniker != "") try { newObj = eval(moniker); } catch (e) { }
                    if ((moniker == "") || (newObj !== obj)) {
                        var newMoniker = this.calcMoniker(obj);
                        if (newMoniker != "") {
                            this.objectMonikerCache[objectId] = newMoniker;
                            moniker = newMoniker;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                }

                return moniker;
            }, "injectObject": function (objectId, moniker) {

                if ((typeof (objectId) != "number") || (objectId == 0))
                    return;

                this.objectCache[objectId] = 0;
                this.objectMonikerCache[objectId] = moniker;
            }, "injectObjects": function (obj) {

                if ((typeof (obj) != "object") || (obj === null))
                    return obj;

                for (var name in obj) {

                    if (name == "$m") {
                        this.injectObject(obj["objectId"], obj["$m"]);
                        delete obj["$m"];
                    }
                    else if (typeof (obj[name]) == "object")
                        obj[name] = this.injectObjects(obj[name]);
                }

                return obj;
            }, "calcMoniker": function (obj, parentMoniker) {

                if (!this.isObject(obj) || (obj === null))
                    return "";

                if ((document != null) && (obj === document.all))
                    return "document.all";

                if ((document != null) && (obj === document.frames))
                    return "document.frames";

                if (obj == window)
                    return "window";

                if (obj == document)
                    return "document";

                if ((document != null) && (obj == document.body))
                    return "document.body";

                if ((typeof (obj.id) == "string") && (document.getElementById(obj.id) == obj))
                    return "document.getElementById(\"" + obj.id + "\")";

                if (!parentMoniker) {
                    var objDocument = obj.ownerDocument || obj.document;
                    var ownerFrame = (objDocument && objDocument.defaultView) ? objDocument.defaultView.frameElement : null;

                    if (ownerFrame) {
                        if (obj == objDocument.defaultView)
                            return this.calcMoniker(ownerFrame) + ".contentDocument.defaultView";
                        if (obj == objDocument)
                            return this.calcMoniker(ownerFrame) + ".contentDocument";
                        if (obj == objDocument.body)
                            return this.calcMoniker(ownerFrame) + ".contentDocument.body";
                        if ((typeof (obj.id) == "string") && (objDocument.getElementById(obj.id) == obj))
                            return this.calcMoniker(ownerFrame) + ".contentDocument.getElementById(\"" + obj.id + "\")";
                    }
                }

                var parentNode = obj.parentNode;
                if ((typeof (parentNode) != "object") || (parentNode == null))
                    return "";

                if (!parentMoniker)
                    parentMoniker = this.calcMoniker(parentNode);

                if (parentMoniker == "")
                    return "";

                for (var i = 0; i < parentNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
                    if (parentNode.childNodes[i] == obj)
                        return parentMoniker + ".childNodes[" + i + "]";

                }

                return "";
            }, "cacheObject": function (obj, parentMoniker, getterName, depth) {
                if (obj === null)
                    return { "objectId": this.OBJECTID_NULL };

                if (obj == window)
                    return { "objectId": this.OBJECTID_WINDOW };

                var objectId;

                if (this.freeIndexes.length > 0) {
                    objectId = this.freeIndexes.pop();
                } else {
                    objectId = this.nextCacheId;
                    this.nextCacheId += this.nextCacheIdStep;
                }

                this.objectCache[objectId] = obj;
                var retVal = { "objectId": objectId };

                if (this.isObject(obj)) {
                    var hasParentMoniker = (typeof (parentMoniker) == "string") && (parentMoniker != "");
                    //var isSpecificGetter = (getterName == "parentNode") || (getterName == "body");
                    //var objectMoniker = (hasParentMoniker && isSpecificGetter) ? "" : this.calcMoniker(obj, parentMoniker);
                    var objectMoniker = this.calcMoniker(obj);

                    if ((objectMoniker == "") && (typeof (getterName) == "string")) {
                        if (hasParentMoniker)
                            objectMoniker = parentMoniker + ".";
                        objectMoniker += getterName;
                    }

                    this.objectMonikerCache[objectId] = objectMoniker;
                    if ((objectMoniker != "") && this.inSandbox())
                        retVal["$m"] = objectMoniker;

                } else {
                    return retVal;
                }

                depth = (depth || 0) + 1;

                if (typeof (getterName) != "string")
                    getterName = "";

                retVal["cache"] = {};

                var ctor = (obj.constructor != null) ? (obj.constructor.name || "") : "";

                if (depth <= 2) {
                    var allowPrefetch = false;// TODO: this.inSandbox();
                    var typeMoniker = this.getTypeMoniker(obj);
                    if (typeof (this.cachedNamespaces[typeMoniker]) == "object") {
                        for (var cachedName in this.cachedNamespaces[typeMoniker]) {
                            var hasProp = this.cachedNamespaces[typeMoniker][cachedName];
                            if (hasProp == -1)
                                hasProp = this.hasProperty.apply(obj, [cachedName, this]);

                            if ((hasProp == 1) && allowPrefetch) {
                                var propVal = obj[cachedName];
                                if (!this.isObject(propVal) || (propVal === null) || (depth == 1)) {
                                    retVal["cache"][cachedName] = this.encodeParam(propVal, objectMoniker, cachedName, depth);
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                            retVal["cache"]["#has,\"" + cachedName + "\""] = hasProp;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (ctor == "Object") {
                    retVal["cache"]["$ctor"] = ctor;
                    return retVal;
                }

                if (ctor == "NamedNodeMap") {
                    retVal["cache"]["$ctor"] = ctor;
                    retVal["cache"]["#has,\"getNamedItem\""] = 2;
                    retVal["cache"]["getNamedItem,\"id\""] = this.cacheObject(obj.getNamedItem("id"), objectMoniker, "getNamedItem(\"id\")", depth);
                    retVal["cache"]["getNamedItem,\"isTestCompleteHiddenNode\""] = this.cacheObject(obj.getNamedItem("isTestCompleteHiddenNode"), objectMoniker, "getNamedItem(\"isTestCompleteHiddenNode\")", depth);
                    return retVal;
                } else if (ctor == "ClientRect") {

                    retVal["cache"]["$ctor"] = ctor;
                    retVal["cache"]["left"] = obj.left || 0;
                    retVal["cache"]["top"] = obj.top || 0;
                    retVal["cache"]["width"] = obj.width || 0;
                    retVal["cache"]["height"] = obj.height || 0;
                    return retVal;
                } else if (ctor == "Attr") {
                    retVal["cache"]["value"] = obj.value;
                } else if (ctor == "Array") {

                    retVal["cache"]["$ctor"] = ctor;
                    for (var i = 0; i < (obj.length > 50 ? 50 : obj.length); i++) {
                        var propVal = obj[i];
                        if (!this.isObject(propVal) || (propVal === null) || (depth == 1))
                            retVal["cache"][i] = this.encodeParam(propVal, objectMoniker, i.toString(), depth);
                        else
                            retVal["cache"]["#has,\"" + i.toString() + "\""] = 1;
                    }
                    return retVal;
                }

                var tagName = obj["tagName"] || "";
                if ((ctor == "") && (tagName == "OBJECT"))
                    ctor = "HTMLObjectElement";
                retVal["cache"]["$ctor"] = ctor;

                var nodeType = -1;
                if (typeof (obj["nodeType"]) != "undefined") {
                    nodeType = obj["nodeType"] || 0;
                    retVal["cache"]["nodeType"] = nodeType;
                }

                var nodeName = "";
                if (typeof (obj["nodeName"]) == "string") {
                    nodeName = obj["nodeName"].toUpperCase();
                    retVal["cache"]["nodeName"] = nodeName;
                }

                if (nodeType == 9 /* Document */) {
                    retVal["cache"]["clientLeft"] = obj["clientLeft"] || 0;
                    retVal["cache"]["clientTop"] = obj["clientTop"] || 0;
                    retVal["cache"]["defaultView"] = this.cacheObject(obj["defaultView"], objectMoniker, "defaultView", depth);;
                    return retVal;
                }

                if ((nodeType != 1 /* Element */) && (nodeType != 3 /* TextNode */) && (nodeType != 8 /* Comment */))
                    return retVal;

                if ((depth > 1) && ((getterName == "parentNode") || (getterName == "offsetParent"))) {

                    retVal["cache"]["tagName"] = tagName;
                    if (tagName == "TR")
                        retVal["cache"]["rowIndex"] = obj["rowIndex"];

                    var persistentId = this.getObjectPersistentId(obj);
                    return retVal;
                }

                retVal["cache"]["nodeValue"] = obj["nodeValue"] || "";

                if ((depth <= 50) && ((getterName == "firstChild") || (getterName == "nextSibling"))) {
                    var sibling = obj["nextSibling"];
                    if (typeof (sibling) == "object")
                        retVal["cache"]["nextSibling"] = this.cacheObject(sibling, parentMoniker, "nextSibling", depth);
                    if (getterName == "nextSibling") {
                        var firstChild = obj["firstChild"];
                        if ((firstChild != null) && (firstChild["nextSibling"] == null))
                            retVal["cache"]["firstChild"] = this.cacheObject(firstChild, objectMoniker, "firstChild", depth);
                    }
                } else
                    if ((depth <= 50) && ((getterName == "nextElementSibling") || (getterName == "firstElementChild"))) {
                        var sibling = obj["nextElementSibling"];
                        if (typeof (sibling) == "object")
                            retVal["cache"]["nextElementSibling"] = this.cacheObject(sibling, parentMoniker, "nextElementSibling", depth);
                    } else
                        if ((depth == 1) && (getterName == "offsetParent")) {

                            retVal["cache"]["offsetLeft"] = obj["offsetLeft"] || 0;
                            retVal["cache"]["offsetTop"] = obj["offsetTop"] || 0;
                        } else
                            if ((depth == 1) && (getterName == "parentElement")) {

                                retVal["cache"]["clientLeft"] = obj["clientLeft"] || 0;
                                retVal["cache"]["clientTop"] = obj["clientTop"] || 0;
                                retVal["cache"]["clientHeight"] = obj["clientHeight"] || 0;
                                retVal["cache"]["clientWidth"] = obj["clientWidth"] || 0;
                                retVal["cache"]["scrollLeft"] = obj["scrollLeft"] || 0;
                                retVal["cache"]["scrollTop"] = obj["scrollTop"] || 0;
                                retVal["cache"]["offsetLeft"] = obj["offsetLeft"] || 0;
                                retVal["cache"]["offsetTop"] = obj["offsetTop"] || 0;
                                retVal["cache"]["ownerDocument"] = this.cacheObject(obj["ownerDocument"], objectMoniker, "ownerDocument", depth);
                                retVal["cache"]["offsetParent"] = this.cacheObject(obj["offsetParent"], objectMoniker, "offsetParent", depth);
                            }

                if (obj["firstChild"] == null)
                    retVal["cache"]["firstChild"] = { "objectId": 0 };

                if (obj["firstElementChild"] == null)
                    retVal["cache"]["firstElementChild"] = { "objectId": 0 };


                if (nodeType != 1)
                    return retVal;

                retVal["cache"]["tagName"] = tagName;

                var persistentId = this.getObjectPersistentId(obj);
                retVal["cache"][this.persistentIdName] = persistentId;

                retVal["cache"]["className"] = obj["className"] || "";
                retVal["cache"]["id"] = obj["id"] || "";

                if ((getterName != "") && (getterName != "parentNode")) {
                    var parentNode = obj["parentNode"];
                    if (typeof (parentNode) == "object")
                        retVal["cache"]["parentNode"] = this.cacheObject(parentNode, objectMoniker, "parentNode", depth);
                }

                if (nodeName == "TD") {
                    retVal["cache"]["cellIndex"] = obj["cellIndex"];
                } else if (nodeName == "TR") {
                    retVal["cache"]["rowIndex"] = obj["rowIndex"];
                }

                retVal["cache"]["$nodeInfo"] = this.getNodeInfo(obj);

                var attributes = obj["attributes"];
                if ((typeof (attributes) == "object") && (attributes != null))
                    retVal["cache"]["attributes"] = this.cacheObject(attributes, objectMoniker, "attributes", depth);
                else
                    retVal["cache"]["#has,\"attributes\""] = 0;

                retVal["cache"]["role"] = obj["role"] || "";

                if (tagName.toUpperCase() == "IMG") {
                    retVal["cache"]["useMap"] = obj["useMap"] || "";
                    retVal["cache"]["src"] = obj["src"] || "";
                }

                return retVal;
            }, "revokeObject": function (objectId) {
                if ((typeof (objectId) != "number") || (objectId == 0))
                    return;

                this.objectCache[objectId] = 0;
                this.objectMonikerCache[objectId] = "";

                if (((this.nextCacheIdStep < 0) && (objectId > 0)) ||
                    ((this.nextCacheIdStep > 0) && (objectId < 0)))
                    return;

                this.freeIndexes.push(objectId);
            }, "getObjectFromCache": function (objectId) {
                if (typeof (objectId) != "number") {
                    if ((typeof (objectId) == "string") && (objectId != "")) {
                        try {
                            return eval(objectId);
                        } catch (e) {
                            //console.trace(e);
                            //console.log("can't get " + objectId);
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                if (objectId == this.OBJECTID_NULL)
                    return null;

                if (objectId == this.OBJECTID_WINDOW)
                    return window;

                if (objectId == this.OBJECTID_CONTEXT)
                    return this.context;

                if (objectId == this.OBJECTID_AGENT)
                    return window[this.contentAgentName];

                if (objectId == this.OBJECTID_IOCM)
                    return this;

                var obj = this.objectCache[objectId];
                if ((obj === undefined) || (typeof (obj) == "number"))
                    return null;
                return obj;
            },
        };
    </script>
```

I left out the last part of the script because it was too big.
In the end this to invoce the script:

```
    <input id="_retVal12" style="display: none;" istestcompletehiddennode="1">
```

Comment: There's more to it than that. By itself, that doesn't accomplish anything. However, it looks like it's set up to run arbitrary code which is concerning.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found what this is. A while ago I experimented with the browser extension TestComplete from Smartbear. Totally forgotten. After removing this extension, the script disappeared.